# SQL query for selecting multiple occurrences between two time intervals

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select, inner-join

I have two tables - one with output data at 10 minute intervals, and one with Alarms data at uneven intervals.
I am trying to get my SQL code to output a list of all alarms with the corresponding time intervals that they pass through. Sample data below:

e.g. 
**INPUT - Yield Table**

*Machine* *YTime*;    *Yield*

A; 10:10; 50

A; 10:20; 65

A; 10:30; 55

**INPUT - Alarms Table**

*Machine* *AlarmRef*; *StartTime*; *EndTime*

A; 1; 10:08; 10:12

A; 2; 10:09; 10:21

A; 3: 10:19; 10:22

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

*Machine* *Alarm*; *YTime*

A; 1; 10:10

A; 2; 10:10

A; 2; 10:20

A; 3; 10:20

I've tried the following code, but it omits duplicated time intervals, which I need.

```
SELECT Alarm.Machine, Alarm.AlarmRef, Yield.YTime
FROM Alarm INNER JOIN Yield ON Alarm.Machine = Yield.Machine
WHERE (((Yield.yTime) Between [Alarm].[StartTime] And [Alarm].[EndTime]))
```

Any suggestions? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Your query should be doing what you intend . . . it should be returning all matched rows.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, the result I'm getting is 

Machine Alarm; YTimeMachine Alarm; YTime

A; 1; 10:10

A; 2; 10:20

i.e. It matches the time ok but misses out on duplicated times...